# post_exists() returns a 0 but the 0 doesn't register

Tags: plugins, php

Strange... I put an if statement for `$testvalue = 0`.  The else part runs and when I echo the value of the `$testvalue` it gives me a 0.

So what is the true value of `$testvalue`?

I need to be able for the if the part to run.

I am trying to use the `post_exists()` function to check if a post exists in the database.  If it doesn't exist, I want to call the `insert_post()` function to auto create a new post or page.  but I need this returning a 0 to work.

any advice on why `$testvalue = 0` is not running the if part `(echo "before: " . $testvalue)`

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php' );
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'my_customoutput');

function my_customoutput(){

$checklinktitle = 'Events 321 Page';

$testvalue = post_exists( $checklinktitle );

if ($testvalue = 0) {
    echo 'Before: ' . $testvalue;
} else {
    echo 'Firing of Else statement but the value of $testvalue is ' . $testvalue;
}
}
```

Comment: change ' $testvalue = 0 ' to ' $testvalue == 0 '

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking the value correctly. A single `=` sign is the [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php). So when you write `$variable = 0` you are *setting* the variable to `0`. This happens regardless of whether or not you're in an `if` statement.

So when you write `if ( $testvalue = 0 ) {` you're setting `$testvalue` to 0, which is essentially the same as false, so the condition will fail.

To compare a value you need to use a [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). You can see that link for more information, but essentially you need to use `==` to check if values are the same, or `===` to check if they're the same *and* the [type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php).

```
if ( 0 === $testvalue ) {
    echo 'Before: ' . $testvalue;
} else {
    echo 'Firing of Else statement but the value of $testvalue is ' . $testvalue;
}
```

Note that I've used a [yoda condition](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#yoda-conditions). From the WordPress PHP Coding Standards:

> When doing logical comparisons involving variables, always put the
>   variable on the right side and put constants, literals, or function
>   calls on the left side.

Comment: Comparing `0 === $testvalue` is a nicer way - this way if you make a typo and write only one `=`, you'll get a warning...

Comment: Good point. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check emptyness of value by using [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function.

```
if (empty($testvalue)) {
    echo 'Before: ' . $testvalue;
} else {
    echo 'Firing of Else statement but the value of $testvalue is ' . $testvalue;
}
```

**Note:** The following values are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
```

Or you can use `$testvalue == 0` as **@Krishna Joshi** suggested.

Comment: Your last line is incorrect. When using `==`, `0` is the same as all your given values, except for the empty array. Since `post_exists` returns an integer or 0, then that's what they should be testing for.